# 15minload.nodata() is triggered in zabbix when CPU load is 0.00

Tags: linux, snmp, zabbix

The following SNMP trigger configuration

```
{Template_SNMPv2_GENERAL:15minload.nodata(180)}=1
```

produces an alert each time the load average for 15 minutes on a RHEL machine running *snmpd* is 0.00 (value from *uptime* command, CPU is really idle).

It seems that zero value is interpreted as missing data.

What's the way to make Zabbix accept 0.00 load as normal data?

**UPD**
Zabbix server version is "Zabbix 2.0.4" I'm not sure where it was installed from but I'm almost sure it's the one from zabbix.com public download area.

Comment: Have you checked the "latest data" page for your item in Zabbix when this happened? This would confirm the Zabbix server is in fact receiving the data.